# How to initialize new value for a tensorflow variable after defining the graph?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I would like to initialize a variable in tensorflow with a given value specified by the user. I have defined a graph which contains a variable inputs_

```
with tf.variable_scope('inputs',reuse=None):
    init1 = tf.constant(init_val) #a numpy array of correct size
    inputs_=tf.get_variable('input', initializer=init1)

#define more ops below
```

I would like to initialize varname with a user specified value. There seem to be at least 2 ways of doing this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init2=tf.Constant(np.array([2.0]))
    inputs_=tf.get_variable('input', initializer=init2) #use this
    inputs_.assign(init2) #or use this
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    output=sess.run(last_op) #run last_op in the graph
```

Both these seem to execute without giving an error but when I try to run the assigned value through the computational graph, it doesnt run with the value initialized (init2) but returns the output for init1. How to assign a value to a variable and run it through the computational graph with the newly assigned value?